# How to format output on Ipython Notebook with Pandas to get side-by-side 2-up tables?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, output-formatting

Loving Ipython Notebook and with the new NBconvert getting some great looking output but wondering if there might be a way to improve things even more..
I produce a series of describe stats blocks that show up like: one after the next..(more than illustrated) Is there any way to get them to be two -up row by row?? the current output stretches out on the page and I'd like to get a more compact representation. It also may be desirable to reduce the font size for spacing?

```
  INVERNESS 
         LIST_PRICE     SOLD_PRICE
count    1693.000000     957.000000
mean   280827.088600  252088.333333
std    115580.920634   91553.077871
min     84900.000000   79400.000000
25%    208900.000000  195880.000000
50%    249900.000000  231795.000000
75%    319900.000000  285000.000000
max    989900.000000  800000.000000 

Median Values: 
LIST_PRICE    249900
SOLD_PRICE    231795
dtype: float64 Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775) 

RIVERCHASE 
           LIST_PRICE      SOLD_PRICE
count     2044.000000     1157.000000
mean    329096.447652   294856.720830
std     168384.682832   122089.475792
min      58000.000000    58000.000000
25%     234000.000000   216500.000000
50%     295450.000000   267900.000000
75%     379900.000000   349900.000000
max    2950000.000000  1400000.000000 

Median Values: 
LIST_PRICE    295450
SOLD_PRICE    267900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by concatenating the results of the describe method for each DataFrame.

For instance if the INVERNESS DataFrame was named df and RIVERCHASE df2:

```
pd.concat([df.describe(), df2.describe()], keys = ['INVERNESS', 'RIVERCHASE'], axis = 1)
```